# Android Studio changes folder structure

Tags: android, android-studio

currently, I am working on a android side project in my free time. As my project grows, I change the project structures so that I can maintain it easily. But whenever I add a sub-folders, the android studio automatically changes the structures as shown below.

[image]

If I go to the actual project folder, it is properly structured as "Fragments" folder contains "SignupFragments" sub-folder.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Click the gear icon in the project explorer. Something about subfolders is in there

Comment: It's a package name that's why is showed like that

Comment: Which BTW should be lowercase

Answer (score 1):

The solution was un-checking "compact empty middle packages" in the directory setting options by clicking the gear button.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the guys using **New UI** in android studio can uncheck the **compact middle packages** option from here on top

[image]